# Handling and returning Mono error in correct way - Java Reactor code

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I have a DTO class like this :

```
public class User {

    @Field("id")
    private String id;

    private String userName;

    private String emailId;
}
```

I have to provide an update and delete feature through API.

I have written the following code to delete the record:

```
public Mono<String> userData(User body) {

    repo.removeUserDetails(userObj).subscribe(); 
     return Mono.just("Remove Successful");
 
}
```

RemoveUserDetails method is something like this :

```
 public Mono<User> removeUserDetails(User userObj) {
 
    return findByUsername(userObj.getUsername())
    .flatMap(existingUser -> {
        // logic to delete the data from database which working as expected
    }).switchIfEmpty(
                        Mono.defer(() -> {
                            return Mono.error(new Exception("User Name " + userObj.getUsername() + " doesn't exist."));
                        })
                );
    
 }
```

The problem with this code is even if the user is not existing, it is not showing the Mono error I'm returning. In every case, this always returns "Remove Successful".

How can I change my service layer method so that it can return whatever is received by the repo method? I'm new to Reactor code, so unable to figure out how to write it.

Comment: @K.Nicholas , I would appreciate if you could mention what is wrong in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you call subscribe, consider it an immediate red flag. Subscription is something that should be handled by the framework you're using (Webflux in this case.)

If you subscribe yourself, such as in this example:

```
public Mono<String> userData(User body) {
    repo.removeUserDetails(userObj).subscribe(); 
    return Mono.just("Remove Successful");
 
}
```

...then you've essentially created a "fire and forget" type subscription, where you have no way of knowing if that publisher completed successfully, if it caused an error, how long it took to complete, whether it completed at all, or whether it emitted an element. So in this case, you're saying "send a request to remove user details, forget you sent it, and then before waiting for any kind of result, always return 'Remove successful'." This is almost never what you want.

You could use something like:

```
public Mono<String> userData(User body) {
    return repo.removeUserDetails(userObj)
               .then(Mono.just("Remove Successful"));
}
```

...which is much better as it includes everything as part of the reactive chain. In this case, you'll either get an error signal, or you'll get "Remove Successful".

However, chances are you don't need that String to be returned at all - you just need to know if it's successful or not. The standard way of doing that (I just need to know that it's completed successfully or not, I don't need it to return a value) is to use `Mono<Void>` as the return type and `then()`, something like:

```
public Mono<Void> userData(User body) {
    return repo.removeUserDetails(userObj).then();
}
```

...which will give you a standard completion if the deletion was successful, and an error signal otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
A common pattern you find when using reactive java code is handling nulls when collecting a list.

The following code is a simple example showing how to handle nulls returned by a Location by wrapping getLocation in a Mono.defer then handling a null using onErrorReturn.

The test code

    List<String> items = inventory.testList().block();
items.forEach(System.out::println);
```

USA
Not Found
SPAIN

> 

```
private List<Integer> clusters;
private List<Mono<Location>> locations;
private List<String> countryCodes;

public Mono<List<String>> testList() {

    clusters = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2);
    locations = Arrays.asList(Mono.just(new Location(0)), null, Mono.just(new Location(2)));
    countryCodes = Arrays.asList("USA", "FRANCE", "SPAIN");

    return Flux.fromIterable(clusters)
            .flatMap(cluster -> getLocation(cluster))
            .collectList();
}


public Mono<String> getLocation(int clusterID) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> locations.get(clusterID))
            .flatMap(location -> Mono.just(location.id))
            .flatMap(id -> Mono.just(countryCodes.get(id)))
            .onErrorReturn(Exception.class, "Not Found");
}
```